# How to add/subtract time from a POSIXlt time while keeping its class in R?

Tags: r, date, time, posixct

I am manipulating some `POSIXlt` DateTime objects.  For example I would like to add an hour:

```
my.lt = as.POSIXlt("2010-01-09 22:00:00")
new.lt = my.lt + 3600
new.lt
# [1] "2010-01-09 23:00:00 EST"
class(new.lt)
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

The thing is I want `new.lt` to be a `POSIXlt` object.  I know I could use `as.POSIXlt` to convert it back to `POSIXlt`, but is there a more elegant and efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long answer:

`POSIXct` and `POSIXlt` objects are two specific types of the more general `POSIXt` class (not in a strictly object oriented inheritance sense, but in a quasi-object oriented implementation sense).  Code freely switches between these. When you add to a `POSIXlt` object, the actual function used is `+.POSIXt`, not one specifically for `POSIXlt`.  Inside this function, the argument is converted into a `POSIXct` and then dealt with (added to).

Additionally, `POSIXct` is the number of seconds from a specific date and time. `POSIXlt` is a list of date parts (seconds, minutes, hours, day of month, month, year, day of week, day of year, DST info) so adding to that directly doesn't make any sense.  Converting it to a number of seconds (`POSIXct`) and adding to that does make sense.

Comment: Brian,  I understand that POSIXct is numeric and POSIXlt is a list.  However one cannot always code freely between these two.  One example is when you convert timezones, you have to use calendar time instead of local time (http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/06/converting-time-zones.html).  The other thing is it's much faster to convert between local time and characters than to convert between calendar time and characters.

Answer (score 16):

`POSIXct`-classed objects are internally a numeric value that allows numeric calculations. `POSIXlt`-objects are internally lists. Unfortunately for your desires, `Ops.POSIXt` (which is what is called when you use "+") coerces to POSIXct with this code:

```
if (inherits(e1, "POSIXlt") || is.character(e1)) 
        e1 <- as.POSIXct(e1)
```

Fortunately, if you just want to and an hour there is a handy alternative to adding 3600. Instead use the list structure and add 1 to the hour element:

```
> my.lt$hour <- my.lt$hour +1
> my.lt
[1] "2010-01-09 23:00:00"
```

This approach is very handy when you want to avoid thorny questions about DST changes, at least if you want adding days to give you the same time-of-day.

Edit (adding @sunt's code demonstrating that `Ops.POSIXlt` is careful with time "overflow".))

```
my.lt = as.POSIXlt("2010-01-09 23:05:00") 
my.lt$hour=my.lt$hour+1 
my.lt
# [1] "2010-01-10 00:05:00"
```

Comment: Actually R is smart enough to go to next day if it needs to:

    > my.lt = as.POSIXlt("2010-01-09 23:05:00")
    > my.lt$hour=my.lt$hour+1
    > my.lt
    [1] "2010-01-10 00:05:00"

Ah sorry seems I cannot give it a nice format in comments...

Comment: Right, in fact that was my point. If you add 25 hours you get the next day and teh added hour. But if you add 100 days and as a result cross a DST boundary, you do not loose of add an hour.

Answer (score 9):

It may not be significantly more elegant, but

```
seq.POSIXt( from=Sys.time(), by="1 hour", length.out=2 )[2]
```

IMHO is more descriptive than

```
Sys.time()+3600;  # 60 minutes * 60 seconds
```

because the code itself documents that you're going for a "POSIX" "seq"uence incremented "by 1 hour", but it's a matter of taste.  Works just fine on POSIXlt, but note that it returns a POSIXct either way.  Also works for "days".  See help(seq.POSIXt) for details on how it handles months, daylight savings, etc.

Answer (score 7):

`?POSIXlt` tells you that:

> Any conversion that needs to go between the two date-time classes requires a timezone:        conversion from "POSIXlt" to "POSIXct" will validate times in the selected timezone.

So I guess that 3600 not being a `POSIXlt` object, there is an automatic conversion.

I would stick with simple:

```
new.lt = as.POSIXlt(my.lt + 3600)
class(new.lt)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

It's not that much of a hassle to add `as.POSIXlt` before your time operation.