# sapply for a vector of dates in R

Tags: r, datetime, sapply

Let's say there is the vector of date/times in R:

```
l<-c("2011-01-01 00:00:00", "2011-01-01 01:00:00", "2011-01-01 02:00:00")
```

I would like to add the certain amount of time(f.e. 1 hour) to each element of this vector. First of all, I converted the elements to POSIXlt:

```
l1<-as.POSIXlt(l)
```

then I tried to use sapply and add hours as described in [How to add/subtract time from a POSIXlt time while keeping its class in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857287):

```
f<-function(dt, hour){
  dt$hour<-dt$hour + hour
  return(dt)
}
sapply(l1, function(x) f(x,1))
```

However, executing this code gives the error:
Error in dt$hour : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Debugging tells that class(dt) is numeric and not POSIXt

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the answer to the question you linked to, `POSIXlt` is already a list. So you're looping over the elements of the `POSIXlt` list, which themselves do not have `hour` elements.

```
R> unclass(l1)
$sec
[1] 0 0 0

$min
[1] 0 0 0

$hour
[1] 0 1 2

$mday
[1] 1 1 1

$mon
[1] 0 0 0

$year
[1] 111 111 111

$wday
[1] 6 6 6

$yday
[1] 0 0 0

$isdst
[1] 0 0 0

attr(,"tzone")
[1] "UTC"
```

So you're applying `f` to `sec`, then `min`, ..., `isdst`.

Again, as it says in the answer to the question you linked to, you *should not* change the internal element values of a `POSIXlt` object and expect the time to make any sense.  Convert to `POSIXct` and add `hour * 3600` to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
f<-function(dt = POSIXlt(), hour){
    dt$hour<-dt$hour + hour
    return(dt)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for an easy way to add hours, check out the package `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
##
Timestamps <- c("2011-01-01 00:00:00", 
                "2011-01-01 01:00:00", "2011-01-01 02:00:00")
dT.lt <- as.POSIXlt(
  Timestamps,
  format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
  tz="America/New_York")
##
> dT.lt + hours(1)
[1] "2011-01-01 01:00:00 EST" "2011-01-01 02:00:00 EST" "2011-01-01 03:00:00 EST"
```

The package has similar utility functions for adding / subtracting seconds, minutes, months, etc..., and the functions are vectorized so you don't have to explicitly use an `*apply` function (or even worse, a `for` loop).

Comment: Or, as @Joshua Ulrich suggested, convert to the `POSIXct` class (this is what I typically use) and just use the appropriate conversion factor for seconds -> hours.

Answer (score 0):

With `lubridate`, it's really easy to change the hour with the `hour<-` assignment function.

```
> x <- as.POSIXlt(c("2011-01-01 00:00:00", "2011-01-01 01:00:00", 
                    "2011-01-01 02:00:00"))
> library(lubridate)
> hour(x) <- hour(x) + 1
> x
# [1] "2011-01-01 01:00:00 PST" "2011-01-01 02:00:00 PST"
# [3] "2011-01-01 03:00:00 PST"
```

Answer (score 0):

To add one hour, you have to add 3600 (60 seconds times 60 minutes).

```
> as.POSIXlt(l) + 3600
[1] "2011-01-01 01:00:00 CET" "2011-01-01 02:00:00 CET" "2011-01-01 03:00:00 CET"
```

There's no need for `sapply` in this case.