# Subtract time in r

Tags: r, time, format

I have a dataset that contains two variables for time: `EndVisitTime` and `BoxTime`. I have made data sets per day (so these observations are all on one day):

```
Date<-"2014-8-12"
EndVisitTime<-c("00:00:32",  "00:04:52",  "00:10:01", "00:23:38",  "00:31:28") # class: factor
BoxTime<-as.integer(c("341",  "229", "301",  "810",  "363")) # class integer in seconds
df<-data.frame(Date, EndVisitTime, BoxTime)
```

I want to calculate `StartVisitTime`; that is `EndVisitTime - BoxTime`.

When the visit started the previous day I want to get the right start date (`date = 2014-8-11`).
My question is how can I subtract `BoxTime` (which is in seconds) from `EndVisitTime` to get the right `StartVisitTime` with the right `StartDate`??

I have tried several options and I cannot get any further as they keep adding the current date or result in a 0 to 1 trait that cannot be transformed to time-date format.

```
# This is my most successful attempt
df$EndTime<-strptime(df$EndVisitTime, format="%H:%M:%S")
df$BoxTime<-as.numeric(df$BoxTime)
library("chron")
df$x<-chron(times=(df$BoxTime/(60*60*24)))
df$StartVisitTime<-df$EndTime-df$x ### This does not work!
```

Your help is very much appreciated and wanted!!!

Comment: Can you add a sequence of code that creates df, followed by calculations on df.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using POSIXct dates, seconds can be added directly.

Sample data

```
df<-data.frame(EndVisitTime=c("00:00:32",  "00:04:52",  "00:10:01", "00:23:38",  "00:31:28"),
               BoxTime=c("341",  "229", "301",  "810",  "363"),
               Date = "2014-8-12",stringAsFactor=FALSE)
```

Combine the date and time into a single string

```
df$EndTimeStr<-do.call(paste, df[,c("Date", "EndVisitTime")])
```

Convert to POSIXct time

```
df$EndTime<-as.POSIXct(df$EndTimeStr,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Subtract the seconds

```
df$BoxTime<-as.numeric(df$BoxTime)
df$StartVisitTime<-df$EndTime-df$BoxTime 
df
```

Ref [How to add/subtract time from a POSIXlt time while keeping its class in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857287/how-to-add-subtract-time-from-a-posixlt-time-while-keeping-its-class-in-r)

Comment: Thank you for your input! This is getting very close! However, I would like the right date instead of the current date. Now it gives the 12th of October instead of the 11th of August.

Comment: OK, concatenated the date with the end time, converted to posixct, and subtracted the box time, to create the start time; answer was updated.

Comment: Thank you for your input! It runs smoothly now! Thank you!